# MultiColumn ComboBox not populating from SQL query

Tags: sql, vba, outlook, adodb, recordset

Good Day,

I'm hoping some can help me figure out why my combo box is not populating correctly, 
This basicly takes three columns from a sql query and adds them to a multi column combobox, the problem is when run, the combo box is empty.

I checked the contents of the array combinedlist ( which is poorly named :)) during the loop with msgbox  and it the array does have the correct content it just doesn't make it into the box

```
   Dim recordset As String
    Dim RecordPostition As String
    Dim combinedlist(2) As String
    cnn.Open "Provider=private;"

       rst.Open "private", _
cnn, adOpenStatic
recordset = rst.RecordCount



           rst.MoveFirst

    Do Until rst.EOF
        combinedlist(0) = rst.Fields(0)
        combinedlist(1) = rst.Fields(1)
        combinedlist(2) = rst.Fields(2)
        RecordPostition = rst.AbsolutePosition

            With InsertWOString.ComboBox1
              .AddItem
                  .Column(0, RecordPostition) = (combinedlist(0))
                  .Column(1, RecordPostition) = (combinedlist(1))
                  .Column(2, RecordPostition) = (combinedlist(2))

             End With
        rst.MoveNext

    Loop

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
'...
Do Until rst.EOF
    With InsertWOString.ComboBox1
          .AddItem rst.Fields(0).Value
          .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = rst.Fields(1).Value
          .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = rst.Fields(2).Value             
    End With
    rst.MoveNext
 Loop
 '...
```